# Why do we use eigenvalues and eigenvectors to build Solutions of ODE?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering about why we use eigenvalues and eigenvectors to build solutions of systems of ODE... What is the reasoning behind this procedure? When building approximated solutions near to fixed points, why do we use eigenvalues and eigenvectors to do this?

Hugs!

Comment: Well, note that linear differential equations are linear in the sense that differential operators are linear operators on functions (or vectors of functions). So eigenvectors/eigenvalues of these operators tell you how they affect the functions. If you want to observe the stability near a critical point, eigenvectors give you principal directions of change and eigenvalues give you the pushing/pulling factor.

Comment: Okay, could you give me a more precise explanation about why we use eigenvalues and vectors to build solutions, maybe some deduction or something like that @OsamaGhani?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864697/proof-intuition-for-eigenvalues-to-solve-linear-differential-equations Check this out

Comment: Thank you @Osama! I'll check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to accept that linear transformations of the coordinates translate into equivalence transformations of the system, if $y=Uz$ then
$$
y'=Ay+b
$$
is equivalent to
$$
Uz'=AUz+b\iff z'=U^{-1}AU\,z+U^{-1}b
$$

Now you can search for the best transformation $U$ that has $U^{-1}AU$ in block-diagonal form or at least block-triangular form. This normal form is widely known as the Jordan normal form, where the diagonal blocks correspond to eigenspaces of $A$. One way to find this form is to compute the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors. Numerical methods like the QR algorithm have the focus more on approximating the transform matrix.

With the first variant, the system decouples into smaller sub-systems corresponding to the eigenspaces of $A$, with the second the subsystems depend on each other but in a way that it can be solves as a sequence of small sub-systems.